# How do I use print operator for a const instance of a class?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, constants, ostream

I implemented edges (as in graphs) using 4 classes: Node, Node_Linkedlist, Edge, Edge_Linkedlist. 
Node has a private int member and Edge has 2 reference members to Node:

```
private:
    Node& in;
    Node& out;
```

Edge has 2 working constructors such that Edge supports both `Node` and `const Node`.

```
Edge(Node& tmpin, Node& tmpout) : in(tmpin),out(tmpout) {};
Edge(const Node& tmpin, const Node& tmpout) : in(Node(tmpin)),out(Node((tmpout))) {};
```

The `<<` operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Edge& node)
{
    out<<node.in<<endl;
    return out;
}
```

This works for `Node` but not for `const Node`. In `const Node`, as the debugger into the scope of the operator it dumps the int values of Node. Why doesn't the operator work for `const Node`?

Comment: Do you want to know what's going wrong (long), or how to fix it (short)?

Comment: @Beta you mean, other than the existing answers?

Comment: Never mind; my comment and @LuchianGrigore's answer crossed. (I would have written a longer explanation than his, but I don't think it would have been better.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is invalid - you're binding a non-const reference to a temporary in the constructor - `Node(tmpin)` and `Node(tmpout)` are temporaries - and running into undefined behavior. To support `const`, you either need to make your members `const`, pointers or make them objects instead of references.

Personally, I would make them smart pointers:

```
private:
  std::shared_ptr<Node> in;
  std::shared_ptr<Node> out;
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if it'd require the members to be const. Thanks!